# Javascript - Structure for a look-up table

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I am not quite sure if the wording in the title accurately describes what I am looking to do, allow me to explain:

Suppose in a game, you get different type of points from leveling up.
But the amount of points of each type you get each level can be arbitrary.

For example, 
I get 3 `offensive` point for every 2 level.
But I get 2 `defensive` point at level 2, 4, 5, and 6 say.
And perhaps 1 `supportive` point at every level except the first.

---

Now here's what I've done:

```
//Suppose I have my hero
var Sylin = new Hero();
Sylin.Level = 5;

//My goal is then to set
//    Sylin.OffensivePoint to 6 
//    Sylin.DefensivePoint to 6
//    Sylin.SupportivePoint to 4 

Sylin.prototype.OffensivePoint = function() {
    return 3*Math.floor(this.Level/2);
};

Sylin.prototype.DefensivePoint = function() {
    var defPoint = 0;
    for(var i=2; i <= this.Level; i++) {
        //maximum level being 6
        if(i==2 || i >= 4) {
            defPoint += 2;
        }
    }
    return defPoint;
};

Sylin.prototype.SupportivePoint = function() {
    return this.Level - 1;
};
```

It's all fine and dandy, but if the maximum level is extended, the points lists will be updated and then it gets really clumsy, especially if I have things like:
2 points every 3 level, but 3 point on the 9th and 13th level or something apparently lacking in pattern so I can't always do it like what I have for `OffensivePoint()`.

---

What I have in mind for this type of problems in general is a structure like so:

**Level**  **TotalPoint**
. . 1 . . . . . a
. . 2 . . . . . b
. . 3 . . . . . c
. . 4 . . . . . d
. . 5 . . . . . e
and so on until the maximum level

In the code, I could then perhaps do:

```
Sylin.prototype.talentPoint = function() {
    return readTalentPointTable(this.Level); //?
};
```

But then this can still get quite convoluted if there's 20 level with 5 different types of points you can get, say :/

.
.

---

**EDIT**

---

Ok, so I could do something like:

```
var OffensivePointTable = [0,0,2,2,4,6,8,8,8,10,12];
function getOffensivePoint(level) {
    return OffensivePointTable[level];
}
```

Would it be easier if I store the data by the level in which a point is increased, or by the running total as above?

.
.

---

**EDIT 2**

---

Ok, can I perhaps reverse the order of the structure to look at the type first, then level?

```
var theTable = {
    o: [0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0],
    d: [0,0,2,0,2,0,2,0],
    s: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]}

//then your CalculateStats:
Sylin.prototype.CalculateStats = function() {
    this.offensivePoint = 0;
    for(var i=1; i<= this.Level; i++) {
        this.offensivePoint += theTable[o][i];
    }
}
```

Comment: in response to edit 2, you could do this, but it's almost impossible to tell at a glance by looking at those arrays which number goes with which level. i find being able to understand data is valuable.

Comment: hmm, could I perhaps turn it into a "skipping" list?
`o: {2:1, 4:2, 5:3, 6:4},`, then try to work this into `.CalculateStats()`?

Comment: sure. there's lots of ways to solve this problem. my answer shows how i would solve it. it's the easiest and most intuitive for me. i don't like being too clever when it's not necessary.

Comment: @Sylin, Not sure if you are done with this already, but I added a full example of what I was trying to explain ;) I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object to store the amount of points to increment at each table (I didn't use your exact numbers, but you get the idea):

```
var LevelPoints = {
  '1': {
      o: 1,
      d: 2,
      s: 1
  }
  '2': {
      o: 3,
      d: 1,
      s: 1
  }
  '3': {
      o: 1,
      d: 1,
      s: 0
  }
  '4': {
      o: 2,
      d: 3,
      s: 1
  }
  //etc.
}
```

For example, to access the offensive point increase at level 2, use `LevelPoints['2'].o`.

This requires a lot of typing I suppose, but sometimes just having all the data there makes things easier. Making your code readable to *you* and easy to change is always nice. It's also useful as a quick reference—if you're wondering how many offensive points will be gained at level 6, you can know immediately. No need to decipher any procedural code. Of course, this is personal preference. Procedural approaches are faster and use less memory, so it's up to you whether that's worth it. In this case the difference will be negligible, so I recommend the data-driven approach.

Also, note that I used `var` to set this object. Because it can be used by all instances of the `Sylin` constructor, setting it as an instance variable (using `this`) is wasteful, as it will create the object for every instance of `Sylin`. Using `var` lets them all share it, saving memory.

Alternately, you could store the running total at each level, but IMO this requires more effort for no good reason. It would take less of your time to write a function:

```
Sylin.prototype.CalculateStats = function() {
    this.OffensivePoint = 0;
    this.DefensivePoint = 0;
    this.SupportivePoint = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i <= this.Level; i++) {
        this.OffensivePoint += LevelPoints[i].o;
        this.DefensivePoint += LevelPoints[i].d;
        this.SupportivePoint += LevelPoints[i].s;
    }
}
```

Then just run this function any time the user changes the level of the character. No need to pass the level, as the function will already have access to the `this.Level` variable.

Comment: yah, the numbers aren't really important XD
 I am starting to get the idea of it now :q

Comment: data-driven design is very powerful. have fun!

Comment: ok, emm is it an option to consider if I have an array corresponding to each types of points where the elements are the levels in which the respective point is increased. Then write one reader function that is a loop summing up counting only those numbers in the array up to the current level?

Comment: you could do that, or just store the character's offensive, defensive, and support stats in variables and just increment them by the values in `level_points` each time the character levels up. then you'll never need to "sum up" anything. so rather than having those `__Point` functions, run a `LevelUp` function when the character levels up that increments all stats.

Comment: oh, I am building a simulator of some sort and users can freely change things around, including levels

Answer (score 1):

Why not store the points in an array of objects -

```
var pointsTable = [{offensivePionts: 1, defensivePoints: 1}, {offensivePoints: 1, defensivePoints: 2}]; //extend for any level
```

And then just get return points by referencing the corrent property -

```
function getOffensivePoints(level) {
    return pointsTable[level]['offensivePoints'];
}
```

You can easily extend the datastructure with methods like addLevel etc.

Comment: ahhh right, ok hang on, I totally forgot about arrays, wait, let me think  
  
  
ok, so I could do something like:
`pointsTable.append({offensivePoints:7, defensivePoints:10});` or something like that right?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you could always create an hardcoded array of all points, however you could also simply hardcode the exceptions and stick with an algorithm when you can.

Just an idea... that would require your hero to keep track of his points instead of recompiling them dynamically however, but that's probably a good thing.

```
//have a map for exceptions
var pointExceptionsMap = {
    '9': {
        off: 3 //3 points of offense on level 9
    }
};

Sylin.prototype.levelUp = function () {
    var ex = pointExceptionsMap[++this.level];

    //update offense points (should be in another function)
    this.offense += (ex && typeof ex.off === 'number')? 
        ex.o /*exception points*/: 
        this.level % 2? 0 : 2; //2 points every 2 levels

};
```

Then to level up, you do `hero.levelUp()` and to get the points `hero.offense`. I haven't tested anything, but that's the idea. However, if you require to be able to set the level directly, you could either have a `setLevel` function that would call `levelUp` the right amount of times but, you would have to use a modifier to allow you leveling down as well.

You could also use my current idea and find an efficient way of implementing exceptionnal algorithms. For instance, you could still dynamically compile the number of offense points, and then add or remove points from that result based on exceptions. So if you need 2 points every 2 levels, but 3 for the level 9, that means adding 1 additionnal point to the compiled points. However, since when you reach higher levels, you wan to retain that exception, you would have to keep track of all added exception points as well.

EDIT: Also, nothing prevents you from using a function as a new exceptionnal algorithm instead of a simple number and if you plan to make the algorithms configurable, you can simply allow users to override the defaults. For instance, you could have a public `updateOffense` function that encapsulates the logic, so that it can be overriden. That would be something similar to the [Strategy design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

EDIT2: Here's a [complete example](http://jsfiddle.net/HMr8t/4/) of what I was trying to explain, hope it helps!

```
var Hero = (function () {

    function Hero() {
        this.level = 0;
        this.stats = {
            off: 1,
            def: 0
        };
    }

    Hero.prototype = {
        statsExceptions: {
            '3': {
                off: 3 //get 3 points
            },
            '6': {
                def: function () {
                    //some algorithm, here we just return 4 def points
                    return 4;
                }
            }
        },
        levelUp: function () {
            ++this.level;
            updateStats.call(this, 1);

        },
        levelDown: function () {
            updateStats.call(this, -1);
            --this.level;
        },
        setLevel: function (level) {
            var levelFn = 'level' + (this.level < level? 'Up' : 'Down');

            while (this.level !== level) {
                this[levelFn]();
            }
        },

        statsFns: {
            off: function () {
                return (this.level % 2? 0 : 2);
            },
            def: function () {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    };

    function updateStats(modifier) {
        var stats = this.stats,
            fns = this.statsFns,
            exs = this.statsExceptions,
            level = this.level,
            k, ex, exType;

        for (k in stats) {
            if (stats.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                ex = exs[level];
                ex = ex? ex[k] : void(0);
                exType = typeof ex;

                stats[k] += (exType === 'undefined'?
                    /*no exception*/
                    fns[k].call(this) :
                    /*exception*/
                    exType === 'function' ? ex.call(this) : ex) * modifier;
            }
        }
    }

    return Hero;
})();

var h = new Hero();

console.log(h.stats);

h.setLevel(6);

console.log(h.stats);

h.setLevel(0);

console.log(h.stats);

h.levelUp();

console.log(h.stats);

//create another type of Hero, with other rules
function ChuckNorris() {
    Hero.call(this); //call parent constructor
}

ChuckNorris.prototype = Object.create(Hero.prototype);

//Chuck gets 200 offense points per level y default
ChuckNorris.prototype.statsFns.off = function () {
    return 200;
};

//Not exceptions for him!
ChuckNorris.prototype.statsExceptions = {};

console.info('Chuck is coming!');

var c = new ChuckNorris();

c.setLevel(10);

console.log(c.stats);
```

Comment: ahh, and if the level can be changed dynamically, I can make that levelUp function takes in the level as an argument?

I am unfamiliar with `typeof` and the `%`

Comment: ohhhh `(this.level % 2) ? 0 : 2;` ok I get it now =0=

Comment: Well, instead of making the `levelUp` function take an argument, I would implement another `setLevel` function that takes the level as argument and calls the leveling logic. Then, if you are leveling up compared to the current level, you would use a positive modifier for points, but if you are leveling down you would use a negative modifier to remove points. The `typeof` operator can be used to know the type of value a variable is referencing and the `%` sign is the modulo operator in JavaScript.