# Simple way to Check a lot of different Cases

Tags: javascript

So I have been wondering if it is possible to make it easier to do if statements with math.random without using switch() like such:

```
var ex = Math.random()

if (ex > 0.1) {
    return 'so long';
} else if (ex > 0.2) {
    return 'so long'; // i understand that this is dead code because it does the same thing, its just for example
}
```

and so on

it gets repetitive very quickly and I'm thinking there must be a simpler way to do it

Comment: I don't think I've got your question right. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have read the question 5 times and still not clear what you want

Comment: You could use a [look-up table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020635/javascript-structure-for-a-look-up-table).

Comment: The second condition is dead code because the case is already covered by the first

Comment: What about switch statements? Also repetitive, should we rule them out?

Comment: @StefanHaustein I'm confused too.

Comment: yea switch should be ruled out

Comment: Your logic is flawed. A value of 0.2 will pass the first `if` statement, so the `else` will never be executed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to choose a random entry from a set of strings, you can do it like this:

```
var options = ["So long", "Thanks for all the fish", "42", "Where is my towel?"];
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length);
return options[index];
```

P.S.: Didn't Ford suggest at some point that Arthur could be replaced by a robot that keeps asking for a cup of tea? Unfortunately, I can't find the original quote...

Comment: Just to mention it. This solution isn't limited to strings only.

Comment: “Ford... you're turning into a penguin. Stop it.”

Answer (score 0):

Just use a for loop:

```
var ex = Math.random();

var returnPhrases = [
    'so long',              // this will be returned if (ex > 0.1)
    'so long',              // this will be return if (ex > 0.2)
    'thx for all the fish', // this will be returned if (ex > 0.3)
    'so long',              // etc.
    '42',
    'thanks for all the fish',
    'so long',
    'thx for all the fish',
    'so long',
    '42'
]

for (var i=0;i<1;i+=0.1) {
    if (ex > i) {
        return returnPhrases[i*10];
    }
}
```

This will work for your specific case, and a lot of similar, repetitive cases.